# Изменение картинки в кнопке при наведении

Tags: html, css, svg, изображения, button

Столкнулся с проблемой, есть кнопка с картинкой svg, при наведении на кнопку нужно поменять стиль кнопки и цвет этого изображения. Если первое не вызывает затруднений, то со вторым проблемы. Знаю что можно менять цвет картинки svg через `fill`, но чего-то не работает, возможно я сам не до конца понимаю как его использовать. Ещё как вариант вижу, просто заменить картинку на такую же, просто другого цвета, но не до конца понимаю как.

```css
  .imga{
    color: rgb(35, 112, 142);
  }
  .imga:hover{
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: red;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
```

```html
  <button class="imga">
        <img src="https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2016/07/10/119178_chat_512x512.png" alt="Чат" style="width: 15px;height: 15px;vertical-align: middle"> Кнопка с рисунком
    </button>
```

Comment: А не проще использовать `<input type="image" src="путь до картинки">` ? А дальше менять по `:hover`.

Comment: @And не совсем то, что нужно.Как вы предлагаете, получается картинка на всю кнопку, а мне надо что бы как в картинка сохранила свой размер, и только поменяла цвет (и была внутри кнопки, рядом с текстом). примерно как в том коде который находится под вопросом. Только там картинка не меняет цвет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно для такого используют css `background`. Если добавлять `svg` через тег `img`, то повлиять на стили нельзя. Сделайте две картинки (или спрайт), этого будет достаточно. Есть варианты использования keyframes, svg, анимации, анимации с javascript, но это уже избыточно. [Пример анимации SVG-иконки](https://codepen.io/exah/pen/Jxsyg).

```css
.imga {
    color: rgb(35, 112, 142);
    height: 24px;
    width: 120px;
    background-size: 18px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 5px left;
    transition: all .2s;
}

.imga {
  background: url('https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2016/07/10/119178_chat_512x512.png') 5px center no-repeat;
  background-size: 18px;
}    
  .imga:hover{
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: red;
    font-size: 14px;
    background: url('https://www.shareicon.net/data/512x512/2016/01/03/697450_chat_512x512.png') 5px center no-repeat;
    background-size: 18px;
  }
```

```html
<button class="imga">
  chat me!
</button>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!